# How to select Html table row using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am using html table. which is creating dynamically and want to select Table row if we clicked on selected row how it can be possible using jQuery. I am binding that table using AJAX call on success event.
I am getting alert message but for different row selection result will remains same. (Only first row value are displaying for every row click) ?

where i am doing mistake kindly help me

I tried Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#test").click(function () {
                $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                var product = $('.p', this).html();
                var infRate = $('.i', this).html();
                var note = $('.n', this).html();
                alert(product + ',' + infRate + ',' + note);
            });
        });
```

**BINDING TABLE**

```
function OnSuccessFunctionalGridCall(data, status) {
                //d = data.GetDraftedSDDResult.ResultObject;
                d = AllDataGrid;
                var tbl = "<table id='lineItemTable' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3' width='100%'>";
                if ($('#tdDraftSDD').length != 0)  // remove table if it exists              
                { $('#tdDraftSDD').empty(); }

                if (d.length == 0) {
                    alert('No Record to display');
                }
                else {
                    tbl += " <tr class='tr-Highlighted' style='height:30px;'><td class='align-text-center' >Sr.No</td><td class='align-text-center' style='font-weight:bold !important'>User Login</td><td class='align-text-center' style='font-weight:bold !important'>User Name</td><td class='align-text-center' style='font-weight:bold !important'>Status</td></tr>";

                    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                        tbl += "<tr><td function='draftlineNumber' class='width4p align-text-center'>"
                            + (i + 1) + "</td><td function='draftlineNumber' class='width6p'>"
                            + d[i].USER_LOGIN + "</td><td class='p'>"
                            + d[i].USER_NAME + "</td><td class='i'>"
                            + d[i].Status; + "</td><td class='n'></tr>"
                    }
                    tbl += "</table>";
                    $("#tdDraftSDD").append(tbl);
                    return;
                }
            }
```

**HTML TABLE**

```
<tr id="trGridView">
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" class="width100p">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tabs">
                                <table id="tblDraftedSDD" class="contentTable">
                                    <tr id="displaytable">
                                        <td>
                                            <table id="test" class="ui-corner-all contentTable">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td id="tdDraftSDD" class="width100p borderTable table_new"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

How to selected particular row can any one help me on same ?

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Hi , change `$("#test").on('click', '#lineItemTable tr', function() {` to `$("#test").on('click', '#lineItemTable tr', function() {` and try again

Comment: @Swati thnx its working